# Filter array based on value in nested array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following model:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...some id"),
    "lessons" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-23T16:00:00.000+02:00"),
            "subject" : [
                "Javascript",
                "Order"
            ],
            "price" : 60
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-24T16:00:00.000+02:00"),
            "subject" : [
                "Javascript"
            ],
            "price" : 120
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to filter "lessons" array based on value in nested "subject" array.
Filter i mean remove whole object from array "lessons" if for example value in nested array "subject" is not equeal to value "Order".

Expected output (remove object, becasuse nested array contains "Order" value):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("...some id"),
    "lessons" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-24T16:00:00.000+02:00"),
            "subject" : [
                "Javascript"
            ],
            "price" : 120
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried use $filter pipeline but it overwrite whole array "lessons".

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
        "lessons": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$lessons.subject",
                as: "subject",
                cond: {
                    $ne: [
                        "$$subject",
                        "Order"
                    ]

                }
            }
        }
    }  
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What we can do here is:**

- first use **aggregation stage**
  [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
  on the field `lessons` to treat them as individual documents.
- Then have a **`$match`** on `subjects` field (array) with the condition.
- And finally
  [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
  by `_id` and push `lessons` back via
  [**`$push`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$lessons" },
    { $match: { "lessons.subject": { $ne: "Order" } } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        lessons: { $push: "$lessons" }
      }
    }
  ]).pretty();
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d0d401ce4f18674c11053"),
    "lessons" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-09-24T14:00:00Z"),
            "subject" : [
                "Javascript"
            ],
            "price" : 120
        }
    ]
}
```